# How are convolutional networks used in AlphaGo?

Tags: deep-learning

If I understand go game correctly, there is a board of 19x19. In the AlphaGo Nature paper, http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v529/n7587/full/nature16961.html, it mentioned convolutional network. My understanding of convolutional networks are examples in image recognitions. Then how could a convolutional network be applied to this problem? Isn't it an overkill to transform the board into a 19x19 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is influenced a lot by patterns, and as you might have noticed in image classification, convolutional networks are good at those.

You ask if it is an overkill to change a go board into a 19*19 image, i have to admit i have not tried to create an image of it with say 0 for black stone, 0.5 for no stone and 1 for a white stone and train a network with it but i am pretty sure it will work to some extend.

Things are more extreme than that! the 19*19 go board is converted into a 19*19*48 input tensor. (as an rgb image it would only be 19*19*3)
one plane for black stones
one plane for white stones
one plane for empty plaves
and 45 other planes encoding several values whom are helpful for the network to know. (things like, liberties, atari, liberties after move, they are all in the paper but you have to know a little more about go to understand them)

is this an overkill, definitely not! convolutional networks are good at recognizing patterns but they need the right information to do so. for example a [ladder](http://senseis.xmp.net/?Ladder) is impossible for this network to detect as it is not possible to get that information from one side of the board to the other one and back within the 13convolutional layers used, so some of the 48input planes are used to tell the network if a certain move is a ladder capture or a ladder escape move.